# Set values into a map<object, string> from form Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript, fieldset

I'm set keys and values into a map from a form and for every field I'm making a validation if this field is not null. I'm looking for a better solution... To make my code more clean because I have more than 10 fields...

Here is my component.ts file:

```
const map = new Map<Object, string>();

    if (this.form.value.value1!= null) {
        map[KEY.VALUE_1] = this.form.value.value1;
    }
    if (this.form.value.value2!= null) {
        map[KEY.VALUE_2] = this.form.value.value2;
    }
    ...
```

Here is my component.html file:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Values</legend>
                        <mat-form-field >
                            <input matInput placeholder="value1" formControlName="value1">
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <mat-form-field>
                            <input matInput placeholder="value2" formControlName="value2">
                        </mat-form-field>
                     ...

                </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: try reactive forms for cleaner, concise code

Comment: As it appears from `[formGroup]` and `formControlName`, reactive forms are already being used. You can set a `ValidatorFn` on the `formGroup` and check for validations there. See an example here https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.keys(form.value).filter(a => form.value[a] !== null).forEach(key => {
    map[key] = form.value[key];
});
```

Object.keys takes your form value (object) and turns it into an array of all the object properties.  So Object.keys will be an array like this: ['value1', 'value2'] in your example.

Next you only want the properties on form.value that are not null correct?  So the filter names each as "a" (on first iteration is really 'value1') and checks if form.value[a] !== null.  Filters work by if return true, that element goes through, if fails, element is spliced from array.

Now you only have the keys in which form.value[key] is not null.  So do a for each and set your map object you are wanting from that form.value[key] value.

form.value[key] is the same thing as doing form.value.key but since key is dynamic, you cannot do this.  You have to write it like this form.value[key].

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: Explained in answer

Comment: Well depends on how your form is set up.  You need to think of it like this: FormGroup = Object.  FormControl = Property of object.  So a form like this: formbuilder.group({value1: [''], value2: ['']}) will be a form group with 2 form controls (2 object properties).  Object keys extracts the properties out of the object

Comment: The best way to learn is probably running only Object.keys(form.value) and console log that array.  Then do the filter and console log that result. Then do the foreach and console log the key and form.value[key].  That way you will understand what is happening.